# ¿Alguien puede ayudarme con este código?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código pero no entiendo por que está asignado de esta forma:

```
var $j=$j||{};
$j.scope={};
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme de antemano gracias.

Comment: Esta verificando si la variable `$j` existe.  Si no existe, le asigna un objeto vacio.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. Solucionado

Comment: Metamax que tal. Checate esto. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos

Comment: No creo que esto sea javascript, pienso que es php, se que actualmente existe el operador $, pero si no estoy mal, no deberias poder realizar algo como lo de arriba en javascript o si??, muy extraña forma la de javascript de comprobar la existencia de una variable...

Comment: Lo saque de una libreria privada de una empresa pero se me hizo raro